# Binary File Deserialization using PtrToStructure in C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, reverse-engineering, binary-data

I'm trying to reverse engineer a bunch of legacy binary data at my company, so that I can move it into a more durable format.  The application we used to create this data is no longer supported.

I have figured out that the I can describe the data in a series of Structures, and I have been able to Marshal them to a managed environment using Marshal.PtrToStructure, with the exception of one file.

Below I have incuded a sample of the structure I am trying to parse.  The raw data is all sequential, and I am trying to deserialize in one step.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct DrillTPD
{
    public short Header;
    public short Header2;
    public short Header3;
    public short RecordCount;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 999)]
    public TPDHeader[] Templates;
} 
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size=18)]
struct TPDHeader
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public string TemplateName;
    public int TPDIndex;
}
```

The TPDIndex is a byte offset from the start of the file.  How can I add a property to properly deserialize this data?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size = 76)]
struct TPDParent
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
    public string TemplateName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 25)]
    public string Description;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public string Field;
    public double Width;
    public double Length;
    public double Thickness;
    public short WL;
    public short XY;
    public short Origin;
    public short Features;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
    public TPDDetail[] Details;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1, Size=350)]
struct TPDDetail
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 350)]
    public string Text;
}
```

The TPDDetail array in the TPDParent is defined by the Features in the structure. If there are no features, no TPDDetail data is present after the TPDParent.

How do I dynamically let the deserializer know the size of the TPDDetail array?

An pseudo XML Structure of this data would ideally look like:

```
<DrillTPD>
    <TPDHeader>
        <TPDParent>
            <TPDDetail/>
            <TPDDetail/>
            <TPDDetail/>
        </TPDParent>
    </TPDHeader>
    <TPDHeader>
        .....
    </TPDHeader>
</DrillTPD>
```

One last comment:  I have only ever worked in .NET languages, but I am trying to understand the unmanaged side of things.  Thanks for dumbing down your answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a simple instance of your structure hierarchy and then persist it out to a file as bytes. Then you can use a hex editor to compare what you have output against what you thought it would output. The difference will highlight where it is not working as you expect.

Otherwise you are trying to create the perfect definition of your structures and it will refuse to work until it is perfect and that will be hard to achieve for quite a complex setup as you have.

Answer (score 0):

From my pov it is cleanest if you have two classes - one input class with the unmanaged data and a second class with only managed data which has a constructor taking the input class as a parameter and is marked accordingly for serialisation - if all data is managed then the array size will be managed by the framework internally.